# Why I have no warnings for mistyped class attribute?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass:
    my_attribute1: str
    my_attribute2: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attribute1 = "value"
        self.my_attribute2 = "10" # got warning Expected type 'int', got 'str'... so it works as expected
        self.my_non_hinted_attribute = 100 # no warnings at all.
```

The non type hinted attribute could be a simple typo, so it seems I have no guarding warning for my typos... Using PyCharm with default settings.

**Question**

How can I achieve, that I get warning in case I make a typo in `self.attribute_name`?

Comment: you should annotate the return type of constructors with `-> None:`. Can you post the corresponding command pycharm executes?

Comment: You cannot. Attributes for type checkers can be defined in any class method, and `__init__` is common place for that. You can add type hints in `__init__`, they will be treated the same way as annotations in the class body (without assignment; if you do `x: int = 1` in class body - it can be handled slightly differently).

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: unfortunatelly, I do not know how to see the actual lint command what PyCharm executes...

Comment: @SUTerliakov: Many thx, I got it. Introducing the typo in `__init__` behaves differently than any other method. In other method I got the Instance attribute ... defined outside `__init__` warning

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent implementation with data classes:

```
import attrs
@attrs.define(kw_only=True)
class MyClass:
    my_attribute1: str
    my_attribute2: int
    right_attribute: float

c = MyClass(
    my_attribute1="50",
    my_attribute2=700,
    wrong_name=55.55
)
```

When checked with `mypy`:

```
$ mypy example.py
example.py:8: error: Unexpected keyword argument "wrong_name" for "MyClass"
```

sometimes the best way to write a proper constructor is let somebody else (`attrs` here) do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can give a warning for that, but you can restrict the class to having predefined attributes using the `__slots__` class attribute. If you assign an attribute that is not prespecified, it will throw an error.

In this case:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ["my_attribute1", "my_attribute2"]
    my_attribute1: str
    my_attribute2: int
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attribute1 = "value"
        self.my_attribute2 = "10"
        self.my_non_hinted_attribute = 100

my_class = MyClass()
```

python will raise an error because `my_non_hinted_attribute` is not in `__slots__`.

In this case:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ["my_attribute1", "my_attribute2", "my_non_hinted_attribute"]
    my_attribute1: str
    my_attribute2: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attribute1 = "value"
        self.my_attribute2 = "10"
        self.my_non_hinted_attribute = 100
```

you won't get an error. This is not a way to warn you about wrong data types of non-hinted attributes (because how would you do that). But you will know when you assign an unexpected attribute. So you can type hint all of them and put them in `__slots__` to get something close to the behavior you're expecting.